# Comgrow Mini Laser Engraver - Adding laser to Windows laser control software

Tags: troubleshooting, software, laser

I recently bought a [Mini Desktop Laser Engraver](https://www.comgrow.com/a/s/products/mini-laser-engraver-diy-desktop-engraving-tool?utm_source=shopsheriff&utm_medium=amp&utm_content=product-card-grid) by Comgrow.

So far, the limited functionality of their iOS app has been fine for little trinkets for testing. Pretty good product for the cheap price. However, the technical specifications specify Windows as a compatible OS. I cannot find any documentation on how to go about making this work. I downloaded a trial version of Lightburn and connected the laser via USB. Windows 10 recognized a COM port, but Lightburn cannot recognize the laser. I'd like to do more with this than simple pre-designed clip art from my phone. Can anyone give me a brief explanation of how this COM port is supposed to communicate with my PC? Even communication with the port and laser via command line would be acceptable, but I don't know where to start looking for options because I don't have an understanding of the way the tech interfaces with my PC. Also, any recommendations to solve this issue would be appreciated.